# $f$ is absolutely integrable if the region of convergence of its Laplace transform contains the imaginary axis?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, laplace-transform

Suppose that $f\colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ and, for some $\sigma > 0$, $f$ satisfies $$\left|\int_0^\infty e^{(\sigma + i\omega)t}f(t)\,dt\right|<\infty$$ for all $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit, and $|\cdot|$ denotes the modulus. Is it true that $f$ satisfies $$\int_0^\infty |f(t)|\,dt < \infty?$$

I have been trying to prove that $|f(t)| < Ce^{-\sigma t}$ for some $C > 0$ but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(\sigma+i\omega)t}f(t)dt\right|^{2}=\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\sigma t}f(t)dt\right|^{2}+\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\omega t}f(t)dt\right|^{2}<\infty,
\end{align*}
in particular, 
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\sigma t}f(t)dt\right|<\infty.
\end{align*}
If we view the integrals taken here are all the Lebesgue one, then the above integral entails that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\sigma t}|f(t)|dt<\infty.
\end{align*}
Now we see that $e^{\sigma t}|f(t)|\geq|f(t)|$ for $t\geq 0$, note that $\sigma>0$ is in the assumption, so the result follows.

Comment: I did not get why $|\int_0^\infty e^{\sigma t} f(t)\,dt| < \infty$ implies $\int_0^\infty e^{\sigma t} |f(t)|\,dt < \infty$. Absolute integrability does not imply integrability.

Comment: I am saying Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: That is not valid for improper integrals.